# Animate swaps of elements in beamer

Tags: beamer, verbatim, animations

I need a nice way to show sequential swaps of two elements in verbatim. By swaps I mean two elements changing their positions with each other. Is there any specific command in beamer to animate this? Should it be one frame or several frames?
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{verbatim}
q E(x) A
q E(y) B
q Ok() B
q Ok() A
q D() B
q Ok(x) B
q D() A
q Ok(y) A
q E(z) A
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Also can you explain what swap, sequential swap etc. is and how this should be animated?

Comment: I added MWE and explained what I mean by swaps. I need a nice visualisation of elements changing positions, so that it is clear which element changed its position with which.

Comment: I wonder if you are still interested in this issue. If so, could you please elaborate a little more your description of the problem? For example, are the elements placed in some sort of array?

Comment: I'm really not clear on what the output should look like: I think we need some form of ASCII-art mock up to have a chance of helping here.